# Can a base class pointer which points to an object of derived class be made to access a new member which was derclared in the derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I wrote the following code,where I made a base class pointer to point to an object of derived class type.I could access members inherited from base using arrow operator.But whenever I tried to access a member which I defined in the derived class,I got error.The code is below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {};

struct B: A
{
    int b;
    B() : b(5) {}
};

int main()
{
    B y;
    A *ptr=&y;
    cout<<ptr->b<<endl;
}
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, then please post the error message.

Comment: The answer is yes, with a member-object-pointer. But not directly, you say it's an `A`, and an `A` is not a `B` (How should the compiler know at compile-time?).

Answer (score 0):

No, it wont be able to access a member declared in the derived class.
When you write ptr->b, the compiler looks for the member b in class A because the pointer is a class A* and A does not have a member named b thus resulting in an error.

The compiler does not know which object the pointer may be pointing to at run time.